# CSS-like styling class for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, styling

I’m currently implementing a CSS-like styling engine for my iOS app’s native controls, in order to avoid reading a whole bunch of styling properties from a plist and applying every single one on each control.

(Edit: no, **I don’t want a UIWebView**, I need to customize native controls. I don’t want to achieve pure CSS, just something that **looks like CSS** and works with the simplicity CSS.)

Say I've got a plist structured like this:

```
closeButtonStyle = "background:transparent;font:Georgia/14;textColor:#faa"
titleLabelStyle  = "background:transparent;font:Helvetica/12;textAlignment:left"
```

You can easily imagine what kind of attributes I’m stuffing in this.

So far, everything works, I have a `UIStyle` class that parses such declarations and stores all found values in its ivars; I also have categories on `UIView`, `UILabel`, `UIButton`, ... which only declare a `-(void)setStyle:(UIStyle *)style` method. This method applies style variables only if they're defined.

As I’ve said, everything works.

My only question is regarding the parsing of the style string. I’ve chosen to use a NSScanner, but I’m not sure if it’s the best option and would like to have your opinion.

For the record, here is how I’ve implemented my `UIStyle` :

-- UIStyle.h

```
typedef struct {
    BOOL frame:1;
    BOOL font:1;
    BOOL textColor:1;
    BOOL backgroundColor:1;
    BOOL shadowColor:1;
    BOOL shadowOffset:1;
    BOOL textAlignment:1;
    BOOL titleEdgeInsets:1;
    BOOL numberOfLines:1;
    BOOL lineBreakMode:1;
} UIStyleFlags;

@interface UIStyle: NSObject {
    UIStyleFlags         _has;
    CGRect               _frame;
    UIFont              *_font;
    UIColor             *_textColor;
    UIColor             *_backgroundColor;
    UIColor             *_shadowColor;
    CGSize               _shadowOffset;
    UITextAlignment      _textAlignment;
    UIEdgeInsets         _titleEdgeInsets;
    NSInteger            _numberOfLines;
    UILineBreakMode      _lineBreakMode;
}

@property (readonly, nonatomic) UIStyleFlags         has;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) CGRect               frame;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UIFont              *font;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UIColor             *textColor;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UIColor             *backgroundColor;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UIColor             *shadowColor;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) CGSize               shadowOffset;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UITextAlignment      textAlignment;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets         titleEdgeInsets;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSInteger            numberOfLines;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UILineBreakMode      lineBreakMode;

- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)string;
+ (id)styleWithString:(NSString *)string;
+ (id)styleInDict:(NSDictionary *)dict key:(NSString *)key;

@end

@interface UIView (UIStyle)
- (void)setStyle:(UIStyle *)style;
@end

@interface UILabel (UIStyle)
- (void)setStyle:(UIStyle *)style;
@end

@interface UIButton (UIStyle)
- (void)setStyle:(UIStyle *)style;
@end
```

-- UIStyle.m

```
#import "UIStyle.h"

@implementation UIStyle

@synthesize has               = _has;
@synthesize frame             = _frame;
@synthesize font              = _font;
@synthesize textColor         = _textColor;
@synthesize backgroundColor   = _backgroundColor;
@synthesize shadowColor       = _shadowColor;
@synthesize shadowOffset      = _shadowOffset;
@synthesize textAlignment     = _textAlignment;
@synthesize titleEdgeInsets   = _titleEdgeInsets;
@synthesize numberOfLines     = _numberOfLines;
@synthesize lineBreakMode     = _lineBreakMode;

- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)string {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _has.frame           = NO;
        _has.font            = NO;
        _has.textColor       = NO;
        _has.backgroundColor = NO;
        _has.shadowColor     = NO;
        _has.shadowOffset    = NO;
        _has.textAlignment   = NO;
        _has.titleEdgeInsets = NO;
        _has.numberOfLines   = NO;
        _has.lineBreakMode   = NO;

        _frame           = CGRectZero;
        _font            = nil;
        _textColor       = nil;
        _backgroundColor = nil;
        _shadowColor     = nil;
        _shadowOffset    = CGSizeZero;
        _textAlignment   = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        _titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        _numberOfLines   = 1;
        _lineBreakMode   = UILineBreakModeClip;

        NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:string];
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        NSCharacterSet *keyEndSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"];
        NSCharacterSet *valueEndSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";"];

        while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
            NSString *key;
            NSString *value;

            [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:keyEndSet intoString:&key];
            [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:keyEndSet intoString:NULL];
            [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:valueEndSet intoString:&value];
            [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:valueEndSet intoString:NULL];

            [dict setValue:value forKey:key];
        }
        [scanner release];

        for (NSString *key in dict) {
            NSString *value = (NSString *)[dict objectForKey:key];

            if ([key isEqualToString:@"frame"]) {
                _frame = CGRectFromString(value);
                _has.frame = YES;
            }

            else if ([key isEqualToString:@"font"]) {
                NSArray *font = [value componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
                NSString *fontName = (NSString *)[font objectAtIndex:0];
                CGFloat fontSize = (CGFloat)[(NSString *)[font objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];

                _font = [[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize] retain];
                _has.font = YES;
            }

            else if ([key isEqualToString:@"textColor"]) {
                _textColor = [[UIColor colorWithString:value] retain];
                _has.textColor = YES;
            }

            else if ([key isEqualToString:@"backgroundColor"]) {
                _backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithString:value] retain];
            }

            else if ([key isEqualToString:@"shadow"]) {
                NSArray *shadow = [value componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
                _shadowColor = [[UIColor colorWithString:(NSString *)[shadow objectAtIndex:0]] retain];
                _shadowOffset = CGSizeMake((CGFloat)[(NSString *)[shadow objectAtIndex:1] floatValue], (CGFloat)[(NSString *)[shadow objectAtIndex:2] floatValue]);
                _has.shadowColor = YES;
                _has.shadowOffset = YES;
            }

            else if ([key isEqualToString:@"textAlignment"]) {
                if ([value isEqualToString:@"center"]) {
                    _textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                }
                else if ([value isEqualToString:@"right"]) {
                    _textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
                }
                else {
                    _textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
                }
                _has.textAlignment = YES;
            }

            else if ([key isEqualToString:@"titleEdgeInsets"]) {
                _titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsFromString(value);
                _has.titleEdgeInsets = YES;
            }

            else if ([key isEqualToString:@"numberOfLines"]) {
                _numberOfLines = (NSInteger)[value integerValue];
                _has.numberOfLines = YES;
            }

            else if ([key isEqualToString:@"lineBreakMode"]) {
                if ([value isEqualToString:@"character"]) {
                    _lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
                }
                else if ([value isEqualToString:@"clip"]) {
                    _lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeClip;
                }
                else if ([value isEqualToString:@"head"]) {
                    _lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeHeadTruncation;
                }
                else if ([value isEqualToString:@"tail"]) {
                    _lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
                }
                else if ([value isEqualToString:@"middle"]) {
                    _lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation;
                }
                else {
                    _lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
                }
                _has.lineBreakMode = YES;
            }
        }

        [dict release];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_font            release];
    [_textColor       release];
    [_backgroundColor release];
    [_shadowColor     release];
    [super dealloc];
}

+ (id)styleWithString:(NSString *)string {
    return [[[UIStyle alloc] initWithString:string] autorelease];
}

+ (id)styleInDict:(NSDictionary *)dict key:(NSString *)key {
    return [[[UIStyle alloc] initWithString:(NSString *)[dict objectForKey:key]] autorelease];
}

@end


@implementation UIView (UIStyle)
- (void)setStyle:(UIStyle *)style {
    if (style.has.frame) {
        [self setFrame:style.frame];
    }

    if (style.has.backgroundColor) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:style.backgroundColor];
    }
}
@end

@implementation UILabel (UIStyle)
- (void)setStyle:(UIStyle *)style {
    [super setStyle:style];

    if (style.has.font)
        [self setFont:style.font];

    if (style.has.textColor)
        [self setTextColor:style.textColor];

    if (style.has.shadowColor)
        [self setShadowColor:style.shadowColor];

    if (style.has.shadowOffset)
        [self setShadowOffset:style.shadowOffset];

    if (style.has.textAlignment)
        [self setTextAlignment:style.textAlignment];

    if (style.has.numberOfLines)
        [self setNumberOfLines:style.numberOfLines];

    if (style.has.lineBreakMode)
        [self setLineBreakMode:style.lineBreakMode];
}
@end

@implementation UIButton (UIStyle)
- (void)setStyle:(UIStyle *)style {
    [super setStyle:style];

    if (style.has.titleEdgeInsets)
        [self setTitleEdgeInsets:style.titleEdgeInsets];
}
@end
```

Is this the best way to go? Particularly, I would like your opinion on the scanning part of the code (the `while (![scanner isAtEnd])` loop).

Comment: +1 for great project. Will you publish it somewhere?

Comment: I honestly think this is much more work than you will ever need to customize your views the "normal" way. Also, I think you should check out the [What's new in iOS 5.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW15) document (iOS Developer Program account required).

Comment: @vikingosegundo: well, maybe. Let me stuff it a little more to include all the commonly used properties of all UIKit controls before!

Comment: Don't call your class `UIStyle`. Due to the lack of namespacing, Objective-C classes use prefixes to limit conflicts. `NS` and `UI` are for Apple's stuff: you should choose a different prefix.

Comment: @fichek: as an enrolled developer, I know what’s coming in iOS 5 regarding to customization, but I need to support iOS 4 anyway. What I need to do goes beyond that: I need to be able to quickly customize a new instance of my application for each of my company's clients. The simplest way to store the style is in this kind of plist. Being on iOS 5 or 4 doesn't change anything, I still need to be able to read and parse the style.

Comment: @LaC: OK. I tend to use the "UI" prefix on everything I do that's related to UI and does not collide with Apple’s stuff, but if I intend to release this to everyone, I'll do that before the class gets too large.

Comment: In my company we use a prefix of 2 parts: OB for our company, UBUI for the UI module, OBP for a printing module,...

Comment: One other thing to mention: By name convention `-setStyle:` would be the setter/custom property implementation for a member `style`. But you are not setting an object, but configuring many style attributes. A better name would be `-applyStyle:` or `-configureWithStyle:`.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: good point too for the `setStyle` vs `applyStyle`. As this is a just quick draft for now, I'll take your point into account.

Comment: Was this ever published anywhere?

Comment: I have been asked to create something the same would be good to see how yours came out did you publish this?

Comment: I never published this. Now I use Pixate.

Answer (score 1):

As this isn't a markup-language, I'd prefer to use [regular expressions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on it.

Comment: Good point, this isn't markup. Any bet on which is faster and uses less memory, a NSScanner or a regex?

Comment: I have no idea, but interesting question.

Comment: I'd tend to think that a scanner is quicker. It just has to scan character per character until if finds one in the desired set. On the other hand, a regex needs parsing on its own, as it's by design orders of magnitude more complex.

Comment: I guess, you want to execute the styling just once a view is created. So this shouldn't lead to a significant longer instanciation. So you should use an easy to understand way and a way, that comforts you and not base on some milliseconds it way run faster.

Comment: You're guessing right. I usually avoid nibs as much as I can, and such I'm applying styling right when creating my child views. I was also thinking about loading all the styles at startup in some dictionary, which is what takes the most time. Then a single style reused many times will just have to be loaded once. I'm starting to believe I've got some nice project-inside-a-project here!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use [**UIWebView**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) & use normal CSS?

Wouldn't that be simpler than reinventing the wheel which might be fun but you might not be able to do (or support) lots of stuff which CSS is capable of & with this approach you might not be  able to leverage iOS features too... You might want to just rethink your approach.

Comment: No, I need native controls and no webview here. I'm not trying to replicate a full CSS engine. Only trying to ease the number of lines needed to customize a native control, as my application is skinnable for each of my company's client. Again, my question is not "should I use this?", but "is this the best way to implement that?"

Comment: Oh, if you need native controls then chuck CSS. Use iOS styling. It's pretty good. Any reason you are not doing that? Every element has methods to customize it's look & feel. Try leveraging that...

Comment: I’m able to skin a control with a single line of code and a single string in a plist, whereas declaring every property in a plist and reading it and applying for every control of my app produces dozens of lines of code. If the font is declared in the plist, read the font, apply the font. If the color is... And so on for every value. Right now with my UIStyle, I have to read a single line like `frame:{{19,230},{282,169}};numberOfLines:0;lineBreakMode:wordwrap;font:Baskerville/16;textAlignment:center;textColor:#a4a4a2;shadow:#000/0/1;backgroundColor:transparent` and apply it right once.

Comment: Problem with webview is that is very limited compared to objective-c. With this project anyone could add custom rules which do different things and so on